# Best & Cost effective way to run long running process

Tags: azure, batch-processing, long-running-processes

I have SharePoint list. I have written a windows service, which runs every 5 minutes and read new/modified list items from SharePoint and insert into SQL database.

Which one of the below service will be best and cost effective way to run long running service on azure?

```
  VM
  Scheduler
  Web app/ web job
  Worker role/ Web role
  Batch
```

Thanks,

Kannan Eswar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using either a WebJobs [1] or a Function App [2].

The downside to creating an entire VM to host the service is you'll need to pay to keep the VM running. WebJobs and Functions will both be cheaper and can both be scheduled to execute your task every 5 minutes. If there is not much code involved for the task, I'd look at creating a function in a Function App.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer